# How can I add the indexOf positions of a letter in a String to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
 public void guardarPosicion(String input){
    int i = input.indexOf(palabra);
    while(i >= 0) {
        i = input.indexOf(palabra, i+1);
        posiciones.add(i);
    }
}
```

This is the method I have with `posiciones` being the ArrayList and `palabra` being the String that is being checked to see if the String Input(which is only one letter) is found inside it, however I've discovered indexOf is always equal to -1, so nothing is being added to the ArrayList. Can anyone help me? In the project I'm currently working with this is the only thing that doesn't work, I can't change the parameter input to a char, maybe I can convert it inside but I don't know if that will work. I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: right, because `input` doesn't contain `palabra`

Comment: try `palabra.indexOf(input)`, because `input` is just one letter so it will never be inside `palabra`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `input` is always one character, you should make it a `char`, not a `String`. This would help you identify the problem, which is that you are calling `indexOf` on a wrong target:

```
public void guardarPosicion(char input){
    int i = palabra.indexOf(input);
    while(i >= 0) {
        posiciones.add(i);
        i = palabra.indexOf(input, i+1);
    }
}
```

You also need to reverse the call of `add` and advancing `i` to the next position in `palabra`: otherwise, you would always miss the first position, and add `-1` in place of the last position of `input`.

Comment: This works thanks, I can't believe I missed that, this project has been so stressful, that I'm missing things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Argus,

I believe you have the variables input and palabra backwards... Try the following....

```
public void guardarPosicion(String input){
    int i = palabra.indexOf(input);
    while(i >= 0) {
        i = palabra.indexOf(input, i+1);
        posiciones.add(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have converted the code to `do ... while` loop and the following example prints `[0, 7]`:
The problem is with the `i = input.indexOf(palabra, i+1);` after finding a correct value in the first place.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        guardarPosicion("abracadabra");
    }

    public static void guardarPosicion(String input) {
        ArrayList<Integer> posiciones = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String palabra = "abra";
        int i=-1;
        do {
            i = input.indexOf(palabra, i+1);
            if (i>=0) {
                posiciones.add(i);
            }
        } while (i >= 0);
        System.out.println(posiciones);
    }
}
```